# Google PageSpeed not updating cache

Tags: caching, nginx, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have google's pagespeed installed with nginx server installed following [here](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed). I need to flush/delete the previous cached content but could not find a solution. On [pagespeed site](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#flush_cache) its mentioned to use this command:

```
touch /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/cache.flush
```

But I have no success with it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by having no success? The instructions on the page says the files will not be deleted.

Comment: I meant I dont hv success in updating cache so it always displays old one.  Thanks

Comment: This question was also asked on the mod_pagespeed forum: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/mod-pagespeed-discuss/27064241-6eda-4683-b95a-bf66193994a5%40googlegroups.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `/var/ngx_pagespeed_cache` your caching folder? If so, this should work. As Dayo noted, we do not delete the files, just invalidate them.

However you can also just `rm -r` the caching folder and then reload Nginx (to clear the in-memory cache). If you are using memcached, you'd have to clear that too.

Comment: yes its that same folder you wrote above, Is it safe to delete caching folder? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is safe to delete the caching folder. However, using `touch /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/cache.flush` is the prefered way.

Comment: For those who can't find it at `/var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/`, try `/var/cache/ngx_pagespeed/`

Answer (score 4):

try this [click here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#purge_options) for more

```
sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
```